# How to combine custom cursor with pointer visible with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a custom cursor with CSS

it's working properly with Cursor: URL

but can we show both Pointer with this custom URL Image?

like this, I don't want to create an image with Cursor

[image]

```css
.abcd{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
cursor: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/6786/2050/files/Ellipse_1.svg?v=1654343486)4 12, pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="abcd">

</div>
```

Comment: https://ericwbailey.design/writing/dont-use-custom-css-mouse-cursors/

Comment: You'll have to take the existing SVG rebuild it with the new image, and then reference that in your CSS url statement.

Comment: Yeah it's easy but you know I also want to change the main cursor when hovering on the link, the main Idea is to use a custom image behind main cursor

Comment: Good idea to keep the 'normal' cursor. So put an image behind it which follows around. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for a way to do this.